# Is it possible to see the daily reputation history of a group of users?

Tags: support, reputation, api

For research purpose, I would like to see the reputation history of a number of users. The reputation history API does not include events such as penalty due to downvoting other users' answers. So the daily reputation history reconstructed from that API may not be accurate. Is there an alternative to have an accurate record or estimate of a number of users' reputation history on daily level?

Answer (score 5):

No, that is not possible with public available sources if you insist on having access to downvotes on answers by users or the red-flag penalties. The rest is available from the Votes table in the database schema.

If you're willing to work with Stack Exchange and sign a Non Disclosure Agreement you might be able to get data that is not publicly available.
Make sure you have a decent research plan, what your hypothesis is and where you need the data for, among other things.

I'm not sure if they are open for sharing down vote data of individual users with research partners.

Use the [Contact Us](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact) link at the bottom of each page to get into contact with Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 4):

No, there is no accurate historical record for an arbitrary group of users with a granularity of a day. The only reliable way of getting a lot of past reputation data is the [data dump](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange) but it's only updated once every three months.

If you want to research this, I suppose you should use the API to monitor a (large) group of users and fetch their reputation each day at the same hour.

Comment: How about the wayback machine?

Comment: @Luuklag only if you're Jon Skeet, I guess. I mean: most profiles or even Q&A pages aren't archived daily.